# How can I append the data to follow columns instead of rows and add more column to input in sheet input data?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code to append the data follow rows, now how can i change it to show the data follow columns instead of rows

[Link google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LvCBIH20slo-CA3HPQQMId35uN02IxTvE0w-T-fqiJ0/edit#gid=304818981)

[this is the output that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foLSN.png)

[instead of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwypL.png)

```
function appendEvLog() {

  // We will add our code here. 
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // collect the data
  const sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("InputData");
  const sourceVals = sourceRange.getValues().flat();

  // validate all cells are filled
  const anyEmptyCell = sourceVals.findIndex(cell => cell == "");
  if(anyEmptyCell !== -1){
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert(
      "Input Incomplete",
      "Please enter a value in All input cells before submitting",
      ui.ButtonSet.OK
    );
    return;
  }
  // Gather current dts and user email.
  const date = new Date();
  const email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  const data = [date, email, ...sourceVals];
  // append the data
  const destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DataLog");
  destinationSheet.appendRow(data);
  // clear the source sheet rows
  sourceRange.clearContent();
  ss.toast("Success: Item Added to the data Log!");

};
```

hope you can help, thank you so much

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. For the 2 images in your question, which are the sample input and output situations? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: sorry Tanaike which are the sample input and output situations? First -> that is the output, you can click on the link google sheet to see the output, mean currently code shows the output append to the data rows so I would like it to show follow columns

Comment: no problem Tanaike, can you try again by submitting the data in my link google sheet? thereby you can know what I need your support, it is just copy B:C from the sheet inputData and then paste it to the sheet DataLog in the same format from column J to N

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy values from "InputData!B6:B9" to the last column of "DataLog!J1:4" by adding the current date object.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Sample script:

```js
function appendEvLog() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("InputData");
  const sourceVals = sourceRange.getValues();
  const anyEmptyCell = sourceVals.findIndex(([cell]) => cell == "");
  if (anyEmptyCell !== -1) {
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert(
      "Input Incomplete",
      "Please enter a value in All input cells before submitting",
      ui.ButtonSet.OK
    );
    return;
  }
  const v = [...sourceVals, [new Date()]];
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DataLog");
  const dstColumn = dstSheet.getLastColumn(); // or const dstColumn = dstSheet.getRange("J2:4").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).getColumn();
  dstSheet.getRange(1, dstColumn + 1, v.length).setValues(v);
  sourceRange.clearContent();
  ss.toast("Success: Item Added to the data Log!");
}
```

#### Note:

- This modified script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change it, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

### Added:

From your following reply,

> That is what I expected, but I still miss column C which hasn't been copied to the sheet DataLog, can you add more of it to help?

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function appendEvLog() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceRange = ss.getSheetByName("InputData").getRange("B6:C8");
  const sourceVals = sourceRange.getValues();
  const anyEmptyCell = sourceVals.findIndex(([cell]) => cell == "");
  if (anyEmptyCell !== -1) {
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert(
      "Input Incomplete",
      "Please enter a value in All input cells before submitting",
      ui.ButtonSet.OK
    );
    return;
  }
  const v = [...sourceVals, Array(2).fill(new Date())];
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DataLog");
  const dstColumn = dstSheet.getLastColumn(); // or const dstColumn = dstSheet.getRange("J2:4").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).getColumn();
  dstSheet.getRange(1, dstColumn + 1, v.length, v[0].length).setValues(v);
  sourceRange.clearContent();
  ss.toast("Success: Item Added to the data Log!");
}
```

Comment: great! That is what I expected, but I still miss column C which hasn't been copied to the sheet DataLog, can you add more of it to help?

Comment: @abs Thank you for replying. From your reply, do you want to use "InputData!B6:C8" as the source cells? From your showing script, I used `const sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("InputData");` as the source range. I apologize for this. Now, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: sorry Tanaike, you want to use "InputData!B6:C8" as the source cells?-> yes
because I thought that I can change the range without impacting to code but I am wrong, when I change the range from B6:C8 it shows an error, so can you change to help and extend your code in case I want to add more columns?

Comment: @abs Thank you for replying. About `but I am wrong, when I change the range from B6:C8 it show an error, so can you change to help`, unfortunately, when I tested my added script with your provided Spreadsheet, no error occurs. I apologize that no error occurs. I'm worried that you might have miscopied my script or you might have changed the Spreadsheet. So, in this case, it is required to know your current script and your Spreadsheet. Can you provide it?

Comment: Thank you Tanaike, for the last code that you just provided has worked without showing an error. thank you for your support very strong

Comment: yes Tanaike, I already accepted

Comment: sorry Tanaike, can you help me with one more question how can I convert new date() to format(dd/mmm/yyyy)

Comment: @abs About your new question of `sorry Tanaike, can you help me with one more question how can I convert new date() to format(dd/mmm/yyyy)`, how about  using [formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)?